# Database is not updated on Paypal transaction with php

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate paypal with my website.
What I have tried is :

I took a form with some necessary fields.and posted it to payments.php.

Now from here transaction starts,and after successful transaction it should populate my database's table.

But I am wondering that after transaction it moves to success page But not updating my database.

I have followed this [article](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration)

Please Help.

Comment: Check if you have specified notify_url and return_url in your code.

Comment: I have already specified.that is why it moves to return_url(success page) after transaction

Comment: IPN is on and the url value is set to payments.php?

Comment: Weird...Change the return_url value to notify_url and in payments.php put a debug of paypal returned values...and then check if it is getting into db